# WebView for iPad is not loading a page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, webview

I'm realising an app (universal for iphone and ipad) which basically loads a webpage. The webview for iPhone is loading correctly, but the iPad WebView is doing nothing?!

Heres my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webViewiPad;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize webViewiPad = _webViewiPad;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.at"]]];
    [self.webViewiPad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.at"]]];
}
```

Comment: You don't instantiate either of your web views.

Comment: Check your internet connection in ipad

Comment: internet connection is working...

Comment: did you check that your webViewiPad is not nil? It's 2 different views.

Answer (score 0):

when ViewController is loaded do this:

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

   self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  }
 else
 {
   self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 }
```

**Bind webViewiPad to iPad Xib and webView to iPhone Xib respectively**

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //load differnt xib according to iphone and ipad
{
    [self.webViewiPad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.at"]]];

 }
 else
 {
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.at"]]];

 }
```

Comment: This is not quite related to the problem I believe.

Comment: thanks. but it has changed not that much. iphone is working, ipad is loading nothing.

Comment: thanks but i'm working with xcode 4.4 and storyboard. so there is no xib file and "autorelease" is not allowed because i work with automatic reference counting.